Bad behavior when remaining Public hostname in a Cloudfalre tunnel
What is the issue you’re encountering
When changing a Public Hostname in a tunnel with multiple rules sharing the same hostname, it overrides the DNS record of the tunnel, leaving the remaining rules abandoned.
What steps have you taken to resolve the issue?
Rename the DNS record back directly from the DNS management page.
What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Create a tunnel.
Set up multiple Public Hostnames under the same domain (e.g., example.com), for different paths:


example.com /v1/users
example.com /v1/groups
example.com /v1/locations
example.com *


Change one of the rules’ hostname (e.g., example.com → example-old..com).

After making the change, the DNS record for example.com is removed from the tunnel, causing all the other rules using example.com to be abandoned, which is unexpected.

Bonus issue: When attempting to change the rule back (e.g., example-old..com → example..com), the DNS record for example.com is not restored.


This behavior is misleading and can lead to unexpected DNS issues.
A more intuitive approach would be to create a new DNS record for example-old.com without modifying example.com, especially when example.com is still actively in use.
Additionally, DNS management should be decoupled from Public Hostname updates to prevent such unintended consequences.
Will appreciate your comments on this
